# to match a string and an integer in perl

Tags: perl, matching

I have a string of numbers, like "4 2 6 7", and a variable `i` which is an integer. How can I decide if `i` is included in the string? The code is in perl...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this function:

```
my $string = "4 2 6 7";
my $i = 4;
if ( $string =~ /\b$i\b/ ) {
    print "$string contains $i\n";
}
```

Comment: If the string contains "3.0" and `i` is 3, then your code will not match. Better is the split/grep solution from Himadri Choudhury.

Comment: yes it will, but it would also match when i is 0.  however, "i which is an integer" leads me to thing the "string of numbers" is in fact a "string of integers"

Comment: Yes `i` is an integer, but he didn't say that the numbers in the string will be integers.

Comment: He didn't say they are always separated by spaces either; what about commas, semicolons, or even `.`?  At some point you have to take examples at face value.

Comment: Yes that's correct, that's because i just added it in the comment as a "hint". Sometimes not everybody creates examples that match the application. And if a string contains numbers, i think it is not so unlikely that it can be floating point numbers. If he or someone other reads the question with a similiar problem he already get the solution from the comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can use split to create an array from the string "4 2 6 7", and then use grep to search the array.

```
$ perl -wle 'if ( grep {$_ eq $i} split(" ", "4 2 6 7") ) {print "matched\n";}'
```

EDIT:
Or you can use '==' instead of 'eq' as the comparison operator to match numbers instead of strings.

Comment: "eq" is a string comparision. Better is "==" then "3.0" and "3" will also match. That is probably what someone wants.

Comment: @Sid. Good point. It's worth mentioning the difference between 'eq' and '=='.

Answer (score 2):

For the fun of it, the `~~` smart match operator:

```
use 5.012;
my $string = "4 2 6 7";
my @test = split /\s+/, $string;

for( 0 .. 9 ) {
    say "$_ is contained in $string" if $_ ~~ @test;
}
```

A good discussion on the power of the smart match operator is found in [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail).  It can be a little tricky, since it's not an associative operator, and the rules are deeply rooted in DWIMery rather than consistency.  But it's very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression to match the variable i with a word boundary (assuming your string of numbers have a space after each integer):

```
/\b$i\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that does not care about the delimeters or formatting of your string. It just extracts sequences of digits and compares them to the search pattern.

I made it into a sub and a functional program, for convenience.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = "4 22 6 7";
my $i = shift; # number you want to search for
print "Checking '$string' for: '$i'\n";
print "Result is: ", (is_in($string, $i) ? "Yes" : "No");

sub is_in {
    my ($string, $i) = @_;
    while ( $string =~ /(\d+)/g ) {
        return 1 if ( $1 == $i );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
C:\perl>t4.pl 4
Checking '4 22 6 7' for: '4'
Result is: Yes
C:\perl>t4.pl 22
checking '4 22 6 7' for: '22'
Result is: Yes
C:\perl>t4.pl 2
checking '4 22 6 7' for: '2'
Result is: No
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with the help of [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function.

```
use warnings;

my $string = "4 2 6 7";
my $i = 6; #use any value of $i

my @x = split / /, $string;
my $count = 0;

foreach (@x)
{
     if($_ == $i) 
     { 
     print "matched at position $count"; die $!;
     }

$count++;
}
print "integer doesn't found in string";
```

Try it on codepad: http://codepad.org/f5a86c9s